# google checkout call back function doesn't work

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment, google-checkout, payment-processing

I have problem in google checkout. I have set my googleCallBack url "https://www.mysite.com/orders/googleCallBack" but it gives error

```
We encountered an error trying to access your server at https://www.mysite.com/orders/googleCallBack -- the error we got is java.io.IOException: Error 'SSL_CERTIFICATE_ERROR' connecting to url 'https://https://www.mysite.com/orders/googleCallBack'. 
More documentation for this error.
```

I check my goDaddy SSL certificate and validate it. But its working fine but googleCheckout give me an error. Actually order place successfully on Google Checkout but after callback  on our site doesn't place order.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Follow the documentation of that error, it should tell you what you need to do. Also these links might be helpful: http://goo.gl/9tWRB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your [SSL Certificate installation](http://support.google.com/checkout/sell/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=59779) and make sure that any required intermediate certificates are also installed - I use GoDaddy too and (at least on IIS) had to install intermediate certificates.

Google has [list of Certificate Authorities (CA)](http://support.google.com/checkout/sell/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=134466&from=57856&rd=1) they accept - and even if you can browse to your site successfully, the certificate chain to a listed CA may not be present (e.g. because you need to install the intermediate cert).